# Wordpress how to update database field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a plugin where the admin can create booking forms and assign them to users.

When the user accesses their account, they see a list of all the forms assigned to them. Click on a form link takes them to the form - The form link has a query variable in the link i.e. `yoursite.com/booking-form/?booking-id=[FORM ID NUMBER]`

I've coded this page to grab the info of the form from the form ID.

When the form is complete and submitted, I want to update a result in the database wp_postmeta table. The field is called 'wedding_hidden_is_completed' and when the form is submitted I wish to change the value to '1' (currently it is empty)

I am using the following code to update my DB:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_booking_form'])) {

$wpdb->update( 
            'wp_postmeta', 
            array(
                'wedding_hidden_is_completed' => 1,
            ),
            array(
                'post_id' => $booking_form_id,

            ) 
        );
}
```

The $booking_form_id variable is set earlier on in the page using the following code, which takes the value from the url query string:

```
$booking_form_id = get_query_var( 'booking-id' );
```

however, when I submit the form, my field doesn't update. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `$wpdb` for this...

Comment: @Mihai just turned it on, getting "Unknown column 'wedding_hidden_is_completed' in 'field list'"

Comment: @mevius what should I be using?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta As to your error wedding_hidden_is_completed is probably a meta_key in that table,not a column

Comment: @mevius perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the WPDB global unless you have to. Wordpress provides a simple function for this. As long as the booking is a post.

```
update_post_meta( $booking_form_id, 'wedding_hidden_is_completed', '1' );
```